# How to list all available locale keys in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

My locale file has become unwieldy with a bunch of nested keys. Is there a way to get a list of all available locale keys, or all locale keys from a single locale file?

For eg.

```
en:
  car:
     honda:
          civic:
               name: 'Civic'
               description: 'Entry Level Sedan'
     ferrari:
          la_ferrari:
               name: 'La Ferrari'
               description: 'Supercar'
```

This locale should return the list of keys, which in this case is

```
['en.car.honda.civic.name', 'en.car.honda.civic.description',
'en.ferrari.la_ferrari.name', 'en.car.ferrari.la_ferrari.name.description']
```

Is there a Rails (I18n) helper to do this?
The other way is to iterate over the parsed YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a script I've written when I had to deal with this. Working great for me.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'yaml'

filename = if ARGV.length == 1
  ARGV[0]
elsif ARGV.length == 0
  "/path/to/project/config/locales/new.yml"
end

unless filename
  puts "Usage: flat_print.rb filename"
  exit(1)
end

hash = YAML.load_file(filename)
hash = hash[hash.keys.first]

def recurse(obj, current_path = [], &block)
  if obj.is_a?(String)
    path = current_path.join('.')
    yield [path, obj]
  elsif obj.is_a?(Hash)
    obj.each do |k, v|
      recurse(v, current_path + [k], &block)
    end
  end
end

recurse(hash) do |path, value|
  puts path
end
```

Answer (score 9):

To get an array of available locales:

```
I18n.available_locales
```

I recommend avoiding putting multiple locales in one YAML file. If you need to do so for some processing-related reason, you can always concatenate the files on the fly with, e.g., your *NIX shell:

...to a file

```
cat my_app/config/locales/*.yml >> locales.yml
```

...or to another processs

```
cat my_app/config/locales/*.yml | command_that_takes_stdin -
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not pretend that this is a uniqe right solution, but this code works for me.

```
# config/initializers/i18n.rb
module I18n
  class << self
    def get_keys(hsh = nil, parent = nil, ary = [])
      hsh = YAML.load_file("config/locales/en.yml") unless hsh
      keys = hsh.keys
      keys.each do |key|
        if hsh.fetch(key).is_a?(Hash)
          get_keys(hsh.fetch(key), "#{parent}.#{key}", ary)
        else
          keys.each do |another|
            ary << "#{parent}.#{another}"[1..-1]
          end
        end
      end
      ary.uniq
    end
  end
end
```

Result

```
[14] pry(main)> I18n.get_keys
=> ["en.car.honda.civic.name", "en.car.honda.civic.description", "en.car.ferrari.la_ferrari.name", "en.car.ferrari.la_ferrari.description", "en.car.suzuki.escudo.name", "en.car.suzuki.escudo.description"]
```

My `en.yml`

```
en:
  car:
    honda:
      civic:
        name: 'Civic'
        description: 'Entry Level Sedan'
    ferrari:
      la_ferrari:
        name: 'La Ferrari'
        description: 'Supercar'
    suzuki:
      escudo:
        name: 'Escudo'
        description: 'SUV'
```